# How to make a @ManyToOne field mandatory in JPA2?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am designing the persistence repository for an app.

I am new to **Hibernate+JPA2** and I am having trouble **creating more complex relationships** in this case a **Foreign mandatory key**.

An example (*just wrote on notepad, so it's not exactly this.*)

I have a Top Class called Person which can hold several Posts (another class).

If I map my top class like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tb_people")
public class Person{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public long         id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="person")
    List<Post>          listOfPosts;

    .
    . more code
    .

}

@Entity
@Table(name="tb_posts")
public class Post{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public long         id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    Person              person;

    .
    .more code
    .

}
```

How can I using annotations make the person field in Post mandatory ?

I tryed with @Column(nullable=false) but I get an exception telling me I cannot use that annotation on a @ManyToOne Collection.

Thank you !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `@JoinColumn(name=..., nullable=false)` not @Column

See the [complete API](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just use @NotNull from javax.validations.constraints package.

Answer (score 1):

It should be enough to just use `@ManyToOne(optional = false)`