# How to make a @OneToMany field mandatory in JPA2?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am designing the persistence repository for an app.

I took this list of code as example [How to make a @ManyToOne field mandatory in JPA2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858113/how-to-make-a-manytoone-field-mandatory-in-jpa2) , but I need the opposite scenario. 
In my case each person must have at least one Post.

Could you help me with this?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tb_people")
public class Person{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public long         id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="person")
    List<Post>          listOfPosts;

    //.... some code
}
@Entity
@Table(name="tb_posts")
public class Post{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public long         id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    Person              person;

    //.... some code
}
```

Comment: I think theoretically you might be able to use `@Min(1)`, but I'm not certain how reliable that would be.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Didn't you mean `@Size(min = 1)`? It will not be reliable at all, since changes to `Person.listOfPosts`, being the inverse side of the association, will be ignored by JPA

Comment: @crizzis Yes; I'm under the weather and don't have my IDE at hand. That's the failure case I had in mind!